# Spring insert error Failed to instantiate [java.util.Map]: Specified class is an interface

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, spring-mvc

I want to post method and execute by swagger, but I have an error. I don't know this error from controller, service, dao or config swagger.

my project structure:
[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PStEM.png)

AppConfig.java (in package com.project.maven.config)

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("**/**")
    .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");
}
```

SwaggerConfig.java:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {                                    

    @Bean
    public Docket simpleDiffServiceApi() {
      return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
      .groupName("calculator")
      .apiInfo(apiInfo())
      .select()
      .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
      .paths(PathSelectors.any())
      .build()
      .pathMapping("/");
    }

    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
          return new ApiInfoBuilder()
          .title("A simple service")
          .description("A simple REST service made with Spring Boot in Java")
          .contact(new Contact("Unmesh Gundecha", "http://unmesh.me", "upgundecha@gmail.com"))
          .version("1.0")
          .build();
        }
}
```

All dependencies in pom.xml:

```
  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.1</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>       

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>   

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>       

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>   

        <!-- Servlet+JSP+JSTL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>                    

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSON -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.5</version>
        </dependency>   

        <!-- Dependency untuk mysql --> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.9</version>
        </dependency>   

        <!-- Hibernate -->      
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>       

        <!-- Swagger -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>       

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.5</version>
        </dependency>       

        <!-- Local Libraries -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sap.hana</groupId>
            <artifactId>ng</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/ngdbc-1.0.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>           
  </dependencies>
```

UserController:

```
@RestController
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @PostMapping(value={"/tesinsert"}, consumes={"application/json"})
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public ResponseEntity<?> insert(@RequestBody KasusEntity user, 
            @ModelAttribute("init_load") Map<String, String> init) throws Exception {
        Map result = new HashMap(); 
        userService.insertTabel(user);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(result, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }   

}
```

userService.java:

```
public interface UserService {
    public int insertTabel(KasusEntity user);
}
```

userServiceImpl.java:

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;

    @Override
    public int insertTabel(KasusEntity user) {
        return userDao.insert(user);
    }

}
```

userDao.java:

```
public interface UserDao {
    public int insert(KasusEntity user);
}
```

userDaoImpl.java:

```
@Repository
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Transactional
    public int insert(KasusEntity tabel) {
        return (int) this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(tabel);
    }

}
```

Error:

> May 23, 2017 3:27:17 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve
>   invoke SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context
>   with path [/SpringNew] threw exception [Request processing failed;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [java.util.Map]: Specified class is an interface] with
>   root cause org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException:
>   Failed to instantiate [java.util.Map]: Specified class is an interface
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:99)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.createAttribute(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:141)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.createAttribute(ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:80)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:101)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:121)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:158)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:128)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

How to solve this problem? is it possible error from swagger config? Because I confident error not in controller, dao, service. maybe config or other.

Thanks.

Bobby

Comment: when do you get this error? when you post from swagger ui?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to remove `@ModelAttribute("init_load") Map<String, String> init`

Comment: thanks!! Thats great. can you explain why running when remove @ModelAttribute ?

Comment: well, since you use @RestController it seems that spring wasn't able to convert your json to Map